# Maximum call stack size exceeded on simple ES6 property call

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Here is my code:

```js
class Drone {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this._id = id;

  }
  static getCompany() {
    console.log('in getCompany');
  }
  fly() {
    console.log('Drone ' + this.id + ' is flying.')
  }

  get id() {
    console.log('in id getter');
    return this.id + 'TEMPORARY';
  }

}

let drone = new Drone('A12');
console.log('drone id: ' + drone.id);
```

When I run this from index.html, I'm getting a 'maximum call stack size exceeded'. But there is no iteration at all in the code.

Comment: I guess `this.id` is calling your getter, you probably want to use the value `this._id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get`ter, you need to change `return this.id + 'TEMPORARY';` to `return this._id + 'TEMPORARY';`..

You were recursively calling the `get`ter over and over.

```js
class Drone {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this._id = id;

  }
  static getCompany() {
    console.log('in getCompany');
  }
  fly() {
    console.log('Drone ' + this.id() + ' is flying.')
  }

  get id() {
    console.log('in id getter');
    return this._id + 'TEMPORARY';
  }

}

let drone = new Drone('A12');
console.log('drone id: ' + drone.id);
```

**EDIT:**

Since OP was asking about why this happened (recursion), I created this example:

```js
// Recursion demo
function CountDownFrom(number) {
  if(number > 0) {
    console.log(number);
    // This line here is what causes recursion.
    // Essentially, this function calls itself over and over.
    CountDownFrom(number - 1);
    // ^^ this line causes recursion
  }
  if(number === 0) {
    console.log("END");
  }
}

CountDownFrom(10);
```

Comment: That works! My next is why would calling what is passed into the construction trigger this behavior since there is no explicit loop calling the drone instance? Any, marked it as answered!

Comment: It's called [recursion](https://code-boxx.com/javascript-recursion/) and it can behave like a loop. [See this example](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/RwNGGoK?editors=1011) which demonstrates recursion.  Basically when you had it as `return this.id + 'TEMPORARY'` the `id` getter was calling itself over and over again.

Comment: I have also edited my answer to include that demo of recursion.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm getting a 'maximum call stack size exceeded'. But there is no
>   iteration at all in the code.

Actually there is iteration in your code, it's just a little difficult to spot as you're using a getter. As the method `id()` is a getter, you can execute it without using parenthesis `()`. This means that when you do `this.id`, you are actually calling your getter. At the moment you are using `this.id` inside of your getter, leading to infinite recursion and thus resulting in a stack overflow. Instead, you need to use `this._id` which will refer to your instance's `_id` property, rather than the getter method:

```js
class Drone {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this._id = id;

  }
  static getCompany() {
    console.log('in getCompany');
  }
  fly() {
    console.log('Drone ' + this.id + ' is flying.')
  }

  get id() {
    console.log('in id getter');
    return this._id + 'TEMPORARY'; // Change `this.id` to `this._id` 
  }

}

let drone = new Drone('A12');
console.log('drone id: ' + drone.id);
```

Comment: I completely overlooked the parenthesis and the fact that the get is a getter. Thanks for pointing that out.